# pdo, delete multiple rows with checkbox

Tags: php

i am learning php and i am new here. can someone help me with a code? The Delete button doesn't work. I have tried a lot, but I have no more ideas.

```
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete-btn'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['selector'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['selector'] as $selector) {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('delete from mytable where id = :id');
            $stmt->bindValue('id', $selector);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="insert a text">
            <input type="submit" value="Insert" name="insert">
            <input type="button" name="delete-btn" value="Delete">

            <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxAll" /></th>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Text</th>
                </tr>
    <?php
        require 'insert.php';
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable");
        $statement->execute();
        while($row = $statement->fetch()) { 
            $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selector[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
                    <td><?php echo $id ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

with the delete part have i problem.

Thank you

Comment: Try changing `$stmt->bindValue('id', $selector);` to `$stmt->bindParam(':id', $selector);`

Comment: `<input type="button" name="delete-btn" value="Delete">` - this won't submit the form. Only `submit` types can do that. I'd suggest to make two separate forms for inserting and deleting anyway.

Comment: The delete button should be `type="submit"`.

Comment: I'd follow the suggestion of The Codesee : check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php for correct syntax

Comment: Also, a bit of advice for the future: when writing a question, try to be specific about what you problem is. "Doesn't work" can be many different things (nothing happens, I get errors, wrong values are deleted...). If you need guidance, check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thank you very much people, i change the input type in "submit" and the bindParam(':id',$selector). and it works.